# what is the relative path to add image in jsp page in a spring MVC project

Tags: html, image, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc 3.2.0.RELEASE.
I want to display an image in my jsp tag and for that i am using this line in my jsp code:

```
    <img src="images/login_pic.png"/>
```

it is not fetching the image. Can you please suggest a solution ?

My **JSP** is in the location : `WebContent/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp`

my `image` is in the location: `WebContent/WEB-INF/views/images/login_pic.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/login_pic.png"/>
```

Comment: not working for me. My directory structure is same but when I use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`, it outputs `springapp` and then the rest of the path is added to it. this is the path where it searched. `http://localhost:8080/springapp/views/kvLogo.png`

Answer (score 1):

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/views/images/"
    cache-period="10000" />
```

add this to your context configuration file , then you can refer your images this way:

```
<img src="/images/login_pic.png"/>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help. i was not adding  <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/"
    cache-period="10000" /> in "mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml". But I also observed the img tag is working only if i add it like this <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/login_pic.png"/>  as Ashish Ratan suggested. Thanks for the help @Rafik Beldi   :)

Comment: you have to modify the location so it matches the exact location of your images folder..i edited the post and added views. i didn't work because of location miss-match .

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img src="/images/login_pic.png"/>
```

this will go from the very top root (this one should do) given that your root is on the index.

```
 <img src="../images/login_pic.png"/>
```

this will go one level above your current location

```
 <img src="../../images/login_pic.png"/>
```

this will go two level above your current location

```
<img src="images/login_pic.png"/>
```

what you have looks at the same folder

```
/folder
  html
  login_pic.png
```